# Finding average excluding the first row

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, numeric-data

I have a csv file with many columns. I have computed average of a column using the command

```
awk -F',' '{sum+=$3} END {print sum/NR}' cpu.csv
```

But it does include the first row that has text fields like Serial number, Name, value etc. I want to exclude this first row while doing the averaging.

Any ideas on how to achieve it ?

Comment: You need to show input and desired output.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+skip+first+line&oq=awk+skip+&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j0l5.9593j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exclude the first row:

```
awk -F',' 'NR > 1 {sum+=$3} END {print sum / (NR - 1)}' cpu.csv
```